# Ambiguous tags: note, music, generate

Tags: support, tags

[note](/questions/tagged/note) seems to be a combination of Samsung Galaxy Note and 'notes' in various apps. Given the small number I will probably retag some (to e.g. [galaxy](/questions/tagged/galaxy)) and just drop it from others, but the tag itself isn't really useful as-is.

Also noticed [music](/questions/tagged/music) which is a combination of questions about generating music sounds, displaying musical notes, and music players (more appropriate under [music-player](/questions/tagged/music-player)?). Is there a consensus on what the 'main' music tag should refer to? There are too many of these fr me to do manually (~1000 Qs).

And finally, [generate](/questions/tagged/generate) seems to be a bit of a meta-tag, as it will always need to be paired with something else to make sense. Purge? Has ~500 Qs

Comment: I agree it is pretty ambiguous, and there should be taken some kind of action.

Comment: I'm curious how [tag:parsing] should be treated... ;)

Comment: I guess that is similar to 'generate', though I could theoretically imagine general questions about the concept of parsing, whereas you'd always need more detail about generating. I don't think it harms much if [tag:generate] is left alone, admittedly.